# Objective-c Releasing Objects in C-Arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I've got:

```
id<EnemyUpdate> enemies[6][10];
```

And I initialize my custom class using:

```
// init
enemies[row][col] = [[MyenemyClass alloc]init];
//..

-(void) dealloc{
     [super dealloc]
      // I want to release the 2d array here
}
```

Now, how would I release my objects later (in the dealloc method) in the 2-d array? By calling free(enemies[row][col]) doesn't enter the dealloc method in the class. I don't want to use autorelease by the way. How should I do it?

Comment: Agree with Jack's answer, but I would recommend avoiding mixing C and Objective-C objects. Just store it in an `NSArray` instance, honestly. The performance isn't going to improve that drastically, certainly, for a mere 600 objects. You can simulate the behaviour or 2D arrays fairly trivially anyway.

Comment: What @AshFurrow said;  And, almost assuredly, you'll want to encapsulate the enemies in a a custom class, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over them and release them one by one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    [enemies[i][j] release];

free(enemies);
```

Remember that `autorelease` MUST not be used in this situation: since objects are stored in an unmanaged object (a C array) an autorelease would cause a zombie object, since there is no one else retaining the object. What I mean is that you can't do

```
[[[MyenemyClass alloc]init] autorelease]
```

as you would do normally when adding then items to an `NSMutableArray` because there is no retain count increase when setting a managed object in a C array, so object would be released but pointer in the array would keep pointing to garbage and mostly crash when you try to use it.

Note that if you are working in an ARC environment this won't work.

Comment: I don't use ARC at all actually.

Comment: but your answer assumes that marcg does

Comment: `autorelease` would be fine in that context.   That entire last paragraph doesn't make sense.

Comment: @C4-Travis: The question seems to be assuming manual memory management. It doesn't really make sense if we're talking about ARC.

Comment: autorelease is just release later. It can be used in precisely every context release can.

Comment: if I release enemies[i][j] it says warning instance method release not found, but it releases them...is that ok? and free(enemies) outisde fors I get an error

Comment: I'm talking about using autorelease in the initialization. Of course it could replace the `release` in the loop. I was talking about `[[[MyenemyClass alloc]init] autorelease]`. This wouldn't cause a zombie if object is added to a managed object, but it will cause a zombie for sure if added to a C array.

Comment: @Chuck it doesn't explicitly say manual memory management either, I was assuming marcg11 was asking about how to release his objects later on... not immediately. I suppose the question is unclear.

Comment: @marcg11: is `enemies` dynamically allocated? Otherwise you don't need to release it, actually you can't.

Comment: I have defined a 2d array enemies[10][10], then in the init I just do what you see in my post enemies[row][col] = [Class alloc] initwith...]. And yeah I want to release it later.

Comment: Then you don't need to `free` it since you neither `malloc`ed it or `calloc`ed it.. It's allocated on stack and will be release upon returning from the function in which it is used.

Comment: And why do I have this warning? "Instance method -release not found"

Comment: @marcg11: The objects in the array are declared as implementing the EnemyUpdate protocol. So the compiler only knows that they respond to the messages declared in the protocol. `release` is declared in the NSObject protocol. So unless the EnemyUpdate protocol conforms to NSObject, it doesn't know that these objects respond to `release`.

Comment: @Jack: Replacing `release` with `autorelease` here could not possibly cause a leak (note: a zombie is something else) unless and only unless there were no autorelease pool in place.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: please read carefully my answer: I'm talking about placing an `autorelease` right in the initialization of the object. And that would absolutely cause a zombie: if the array it's an instance variable and you try to access an autoreleased object because you forgot to set its reference to `nil` in the array you are actually trying to access garbage data. I call it zombie just because it's the same thing but related to a C pointer. Dereferencing a garbaged pointer is like trying to access a zombie object.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Of course you don't get an ObjC _zombie_. But you surely get a bad address exception if you try to use that pointer. It's not the same thing but in both cases you something is trusted to still exists while it is not.

Comment: @Jack: Do you mean a dangling pointer? That's very different from a zombie (what you get with `NSZombieEnabled` set.) And since the release/autorelease is immediately followed by a `free()` of the pointer's storage, it's moot: there is no dangling pointer created.

Answer (score 1):

Like any other objc variable, you would `release` each element of the array. Also, you should release your `enemies[][]` *before* calling `[super dealloc]`.

Your implementation would take this form:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
      [enemies[i][j] release];
      enemies[i][j] = nil;
    }
  }

  [super dealloc]
}
```

**Edit**

> And the warning telling me that the method -release is not found?

That's because `release` is not in the `EnemyUpdate` protocol and the type is `id<EnemyUpdate>`. You can declare the array as `NSObject<EnemyUpdate>* enemies[6][10];`

**OR**

specify that `EnemyUpdate` adopts `@protocol NSObject`:

```
@protocol EnemyUpdate < NSObject >
...
@end
```

Comment: And the warning telling me that the method -release is not found?

Comment: Modify the definition of your protocol such that it conforms to the NSObect protocol. The warning will then go away.

Comment: `NSObject` protocol, that is. Darn iPad keyboard…